# How does failing in a course during Master's studies in Germany affect job prospects?

Tags: masters, job, exams, germany, grades

What are the implications of failing an exam of a particular course during Master's studies in Germany? Is it considered bad in terms of future job prospects in that field? Does that disqualify you from pursuing a job in that specific field?

For example: If a student fails in the exam of a compulsory course "A" once or twice and he/she passes the exam in the second or third attempt. But *his/her field of interest is very relevant to the course "A".* So will he/she find it difficult to get a job in that field because he/she failed in that compulsory course "A" once or twice?

Comment: Not all employers in Germany care about grades, especially prior work experience often trumps grades. In case that grades matter, it's a big difference if you eventually passed the course with a strong grade or with a barely passing one.

Comment: In some universities, failed courses do not even show up in the transcript.

Comment: Job = outside academia? Or a PhD?

Answer (score 4):

**In my experience, it will have minor to none implications.**

- Job interviews barely talk about failed exams, **if they even pose a question about your studies at all**, they focus on what you put your focus on.
- You could check your *Prüfungsordnung* or get in touch with the *Studienbüro*, if they actually include the amount of failed attempts in your *Abschlusszeugnis*. If they don't, you could chose to lie about it.
- Your final grade and internships plus work experience are far more important than a failed class. So even if you decide to tell them, it should have minor implications.
- Nonetheless, I think if they have to pick between two equal applicants where one has no failed attempts, they will pick him/her.

**Things that actually are part of job interviews/applications in germany (in my experience)**

- Hobbies you persue (as an opener for the interview)
- Final Grade
- Your *Abschlussarbeit*, if it's related to the field you want to work in
- In Computer Science, they could ask algorithm questions, although this depends on if they have qualified personnel
- Experience in the workfield (internships, experience during your studies)
- Questions to check if you fit into the company and have the required competency to do the job.

In the job interviews I had, they never mentioned my transcript of records.

Comment: Your disclaimer in the first sentence (now removed) is justified: I do remember seeing failed attempts in transcripts of records from at least one German university.

Comment: You're right, I heavily edited my answer, the second bulletpoint should adress that issue now

Comment: But did you had any backlogs or exams which you re-attempted? And will it be a bad idea to pass the exam with poor grades rather than giving it again if the emphasis is more on the final grade?

Comment: Yes I actually re-attempted one of the two main classes. In my opinion, the giving it again would be the better option since the finale grade matters most(, but work experience trumps final grade in the long run). But you should keep in mind that taking the exam again might consume time you can invest in other classes to get better grades there.